# Finding source code for all geometry tools of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I want to find the Python source code for tools like Merge Lines, Multiple parts to single parts, Intersection, Difference etc. I am not having any luck finding them online.

Does anyone know any links to Python code?

I am using QGIS 3.18.1.

Comment: https://gdal.org/python/

Comment: Do you mean this folder: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/ltr-3_10/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis

Comment: Neither of the above links are to the source code for those tools. The tools are not written in python, but in C++ and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/release-3_18/src/analysis/processing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tools are not written in python, but in C++ and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/release-3_18/src/analysis/processing), e.g.

- [merge lines](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-3_18/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmmergelines.cpp),
- [multipart to singlepart](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-3_18/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmmultiparttosinglepart.cpp)

Comment: is there any way i can find the tools code in python? written by some fellow user?

Comment: No. The tools are not available as python code.  If you are asking about the algorithms these tools implement, then that is a different question. Pure python implementations won't be easy to find.

Comment: where can i find the algo?